# Why does XmlDictionary.Add() return an XmlDictionaryString?

Tags: c#, .net

I am wondering why the `XmlDictionary.Add()` method returns `XmlDictionaryString`. In what scenario would this object be useful?

Comment: What would you consider a more appropriate return type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An [`XmlDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldictionary.aspx) is intended for use in compressing XML:

> Dictionaries establish a mapping between commonly appearing text strings, and integers, and provide an effective mechanism for compressing and decompressing XML

So, for each string added to the dictionary, an integer is associated with it. One of the most common use cases after adding a string to the dictionary is to want to use the integer that is now associated with that string.

And the `XmlDictionaryString`'s [`Key` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldictionarystring.key.aspx) provides access to that integer.

Answer (score 8):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldictionary.add.aspx):

> If the string value is already in the dictionary, the XmlDictionaryString previously created for it is returned.

This could be useful if you didn't want to have to check if the item is in the dictionary before adding it, you'd just be able to use the return value.

Comment: Why would I have to check if the item is already presented in dictionary? The dictionary checks it itself while performing Add().

Comment: Well, I must confess I have never used this, so this is hypothetical for me. I was imagining a situation where you had a function which takes an `XmlDictionaryString` as a paramter, and you can call (for example) `processXmlDictString(myXmlDict.Add("example"))` and it wouldn't just return a null or throw an exception if you hit the same string twice. Hopefully someone else can provide a better answer/comment with an example, since I think that would help you the most.

Answer (score 2):

XML Dictionary is used to store the mapping between commonly used string & integer values in the xml and provides a way to compress/decompressing the XML.
This method is used add a string value as Dictionary entry.This method returns an instance of `System.Xml.XmlDictionaryString` object which represents a `dictionary entry`.This object exposes the properties `Key & Value` which returns the dictionary entry’s key & value.

```
XmlDictionary dict = new XmlDictionary();
XmlDictionaryString dictEntry = dict.Add("Name");
Console.WriteLine("Key:{0},Value:{1}",dictEntry.Key , dictEntry.Value);
```